# Changing Decimal Number to Percent

Tags: powerbi

I have a column I would like to change from a decimal number to a percent. Here are some example numbers: 28.97, 42.83 and 99.25.

Because of where the decimal point is located, when I change the value to percentage, the numbers turn to 2897%, 4283% and 9925% instead of 28.97%, 42.83% and 99.25%.

Is there a way in DAX or Power Query Editor to move the decimal point over to the left two spots so I can get the correct output?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this tool, but if you can do arithmetic operations, you could divide the number by 100 and then convert it

Comment: Perfect. I was able to create a new column and divide that current column by 100. Thanks!

Comment: If you would like, you could post your solution as an answer. It helps people find this post if they have the same problem. Again, I'm not familiar with the tool so I wouldn't be able to post a great answer, but you probably could.